# Hugo categories permalink change URL to slug only?

Tags: url, customization, taxonomy, static-site, hugo

Using the [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) static site generator, is it possible to change the categories page URL, e.g. change the default `/categories/travel/` to only `/travel/`?

Perhaps something like, in `config.toml`:

```
[permalinks]
  post = "/:slug/"
  page = "/:slug/"
  category = "/:slug/"
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Hugo docs:

> You can also configure permalinks of taxonomies with the same syntax,
>   by using the plural form of the taxonomy instead of the section.

So, just add this to `config.toml`:

```
[permalinks]
    categories = "/:slug/"
```